# Having trouble submitting my form using Dojo

Tags: django, dojo, django-forms

I am using Django 1.5 and Dojo 1.8. I am trying to get Dojo to submit a form back to a Django view when I click a button.

Here is my Django view:

```
def report(request, report_id, report_url=None, template='report_parameters.html'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportParametersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            report_params = form.save()
            html = "Success!"
            return HttpResponse(html)
    else:
        form = ReportParametersForm()
        return render(request,template, {
            'form': form,
            'report_url': report_url,
            'report_id': report_id,
        })
```

Here is the html page:

```
    <div id="report_body">
        <form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="parameters_form" data-dojo-id="parameters_form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
            </table>
            <p><button id="submit_parameters" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">Submit</button></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="submit" data-dojo-args="e">
        e.preventDefault();
        require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/request", "dojo/dom-form"], function(dom, request, domForm){
            on(dom.byId("submit_parameters"), "click", function() {
                console.log("Dojo Post");
                request.xhr("/report_parameters/report_id/report_url/", {
                    method: "post",
                    handleAs: "json",
                    data: domForm.toJson("parameters_form"),
                }).then(
                    function(response){
                        alert(response);
                        dom.byId("report_body").innerHTML = "Report!";
                    },
                    function(error){
                        dom.byId("report_body").innerHTML = "<div class=\"error\">"+error+"<div>";
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I click the `Submit` button, I want to send a `POST` request to the url passing the data I have in my form. However, right now when I click `Submit`, the page reloads with a url looking something like this: `/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=Y9gaNMFRWZNXMbJ2L3Ev7A5iKPGTuWeF&param_1=0&param2=0/report_parameters/report_id/report_url/`.
I don't see the `Dojo Post` that should be appearing in my console.
How do I get my form to submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPbgC/3/) seems to do what you want.

The major differences seem to be:

- The `<form>` is actually a `<div>`. The [Dojo documentation for Form](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/Form.html) links to [reasons why this is done for IE](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/8424).
- All the related event script is inside the form `<div>`.
- Remove the `on(dom.byId("submit_parameters")...` code, as there's already a declarative submit event handler.

HTML code:

```
<div id="report_body"></div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="parameters_form" data-dojo-id="parameters_form" encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="">
    <input name="dummy" value="dummy">
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="submit" data-dojo-args="e">
        console.log("submit");
        e.preventDefault();
        require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/dom-form"], function(dom, xhr, domForm) {
            console.log("Dojo Post");
            var url = "/report_parameters/report_id/report_url/";
            var data = domForm.toJson("parameters_form");
            // overwrite url and data for jsfiddle
            url = "/echo/json/";
            data = {
                json: data
            };
            xhr(url, {
                method: "post",
                handleAs: "json",
                data: data,
            }).then(function(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
                dom.byId("report_body").innerHTML = "Report!";
            }, function(error) {
                dom.byId("report_body").innerHTML = "<div class=\"error\">" + error + "<div>";
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="submit_button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function (parser, registry) {
    parser.parse().then(function () {
        console.log("parsed");
        console.log(registry.byId("parameters_form"));
        console.log(registry.byId("submit_button"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've gotten the POST working now. However, when I view the console, I get this error: `POST http://<hostname>/report_parameters/report_id/report_url/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)`. What is causing that?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. The bug was that `var data = domForm.toJson("parameters_form");` needed to be `var data = domForm.toObject("parameters_form");` and then I needed to get rid of the `handleAs: "json",` line.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the above slightly. This is what eventually worked for me:

```
    <div id="report_body"></div>
    <form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="parameters_form" data-dojo-id="parameters_form" encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="submit" data-dojo-args="e">
            e.preventDefault();
            require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/dom-form"], function(dom, xhr, domForm){
                var url = "/report_parameters/report_id/report_url/"
                var data = domForm.toObject("parameters_form")
                xhr(url, {
                    method: "post",
                    data: data,
                }).then(
                    function(response){
                        alert(response);
                        dom.byId("report_body").innerHTML = "Report!";
                    },
                    function(error){
                        dom.byId("report_body").innerHTML = error;
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
        <p><button id="submit_parameters" dojoType="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">Submit</button></p>
    </form>
```

Using either the `<div>` or `<form>` tags to wrap the whole thing worked for me.